How do I normalize the data before applying Direct Linear Transform?
Consider a perspective camera looking down at the plane $Z=0$.
A point $(X,Y)$ is projected into the image plane point $(u,v)$.
This is described by the following homogenous linear equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
u \\
v \\
w 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
f & 0 & p_x \\
0 & f & p_y  \\
0 & 0 & 1  
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
R_{11} & R_{12}  & t_{x} \\
R_{21} & R_{22}  & t_{y} \\
R_{31} & R_{32}  & t_{z} 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
X \\
Y \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
where the constants f (focal length) and $p_x$ and $p_x$ (principal offsets) are properties of the camera, $R_{3x3}$ is an orthogonal matrix that changes basis from the world coordinate system to the camera coordinate system and $\vec{t}$ is the vector from the camera to the origin of the world coordinate system.
Let us denote the product of the two matrices above by H.
The problem is to estimate H from n points known in both coordinate systems.
One way to do this would be to express:
$$
\hat{u}(f, p_x, p_y, roll, pitch, yaw, t_x, t_y, t_z)
$$
$$
\hat{v}(f, p_x, p_y, roll, pitch, yaw, t_x, t_y, t_z)
$$
And to minimize the square error:
$$
SE = \Sigma_i (\hat{u_i}-u_i)^2 + (\hat{v_i}-v_i)^2
$$
the $(f, p_x, p_y, roll, pitch, yaw, t_x, t_y, t_z)$ that minimizes the SE are the most likely parameters (assuming no error in X and Y).
Another linear way of doing this is to use the Direct Linear Transform (DLT) to estimate H by rearranging:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
X & Y  &  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -uX & -uY & -u \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -X & -Y & -1 & vX & vY & v 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
H_{11} \\
H_{12} \\
H_{13} \\
H_{21} \\
H_{22} \\
H_{23} \\
H_{31} \\
H_{32} \\
H_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\textbf{0}
$$
stacking these two equations for n points and finding H by SVD.
In the book "Multiple view geometry in computer vision
Book" it is mentioned on page 104:
"It is clear that it would generally be undesirable for the result of an algorithm
to be dependent on such arbitrary choices as the origin and scale, or even orientation,
of the coordinate system in an image". I agree, that would be weird.
But on page 105: "On the other hand, for the DLT
algorithm as described in section 4.1, the result unfortunately is not invariant to similarity transformations. The solution is to apply a normalizing transformation to the data before applying the DLT algorithm."
On page 106:
"This is a rather undesirable feature of the DLT algorithm as it
stands, that the result is changed by a change of coordinates, or even simply a change of
the origin of coordinates."
Can anyone give an intuitive explanation to why that is?
Is this unfortunate and strange property something that occurs in other places?
On page 108:
"However, in the presence of noise the solution will diverge from the correct result. The effect of a large condition number is to amplify this divergence. This is true even for infinite-precision arithmetic – this is not a round-off error effect."
In the book the authors go on to discuss ways of normalizing the data to get the DLT solution closer to the most likely solution. These seems a bit poorly motivated though.
My problem is that I am not working on the homography problem described above, but rather on using the DLT for a linear pushbroom camera as described in the paper "Linear Pushbroom Cameras." by Gupta and Hartley.
The paper do not discuss how to normalize the data and I observe that I get different solutions if I choose mm or m as the unit for the X, Y and Z coordinates.
I therefore need a normalization procedure or the understanding to be able to come up with one myself.
In practice the best approach may be to use the DLT without any normalization to find an initial estimate and accept that this solution may be quite a bit off the most likely solution and also dependent on the scale and choice of origin.
Next this initial estimate would be used in a nonlinear minimization to find the most likely solution?

We find a homography by solving the homogeneous system $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{h} = \mathbf{0}$, where $\mathbf{h}$ is the vectorized unknown matrix $\mathbf{H}$. Since $\alpha \mathbf{h}$ is also a solution for any scalar $\alpha$, the scale is arbitrary. When $\mathbf{A}$'s entries vary widely (e.g., using $\mathrm{mm}$ vs. $\mathrm{m}$), the system becomes ill-conditioned. A large condition number $\kappa(\mathbf{A})$ makes $\mathbf{h}$ highly sensitive to small variations in $\mathbf{A}$, causing different solutions under coordinate transformations.
The standard fix applies normalizing transformations before building $\mathbf{A}$. We center points at their centroid and scale to unit average distance. With $\mathbf{T}_X$ normalizing world points and $\mathbf{T}_u$ normalizing image points, we solve:
$$(\mathbf{T}_u \mathbf{A}\mathbf{T}_X^{-1}) \mathbf{\tilde{h}} = \mathbf{0}$$
and recover $\mathbf{H}$ by un-normalizing. This improves conditioning without changing the underlying geometry. The same issue affects many homogeneous least-squares problems, including fundamental matrix estimation.
For better results, we can use normalized DLT as initialization for nonlinear optimization:
$$SE = \sum_{i}\bigl(\hat{u}_i - u_i\bigr)^2 + \bigl(\hat{v}_i - v_i\bigr)^2$$
where $\hat{u}_i,\hat{v}_i$ are predicted image coordinates. For pushbroom cameras, the same principles apply - either normalize appropriately or use DLT to seed nonlinear optimization.​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
